# Wordpress content shows this character â€‹â€‹

Tags: encoding

In my website this characters â€‹â€‹ showing up on everywhere in blog content and title, after many hours of searching and googling cant find any useful answer i tried this meta but no luck

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Is there any way to rid-off this `â€‹â€‹` And many other characters:
`â€˜`
`â`
`�`

Also tried Plugin search and replace but the character is not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after little bit search on google & http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php , After a long time answered my own question thought maybe it will help someone.

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities(YOUR_STRING, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false)));
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but it doesn't solve the actual problem and that's that the characters are encoded wrong in the database. It shouldn't be a solution to change your entire theme for this. Did you by any change migrate your database? Because this always happens when you import a database into a new one with different encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you search your content for these characters `â€˜ â �` you will not find them, because they are not there. Characters `â€˜ â �` like these are a sign, that the character encoding in the frontend does not match with that from the database. Normaly wordpress used for database, file endcoding and character encoding UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually I'm trying to add post from my old non wordpress website to wordpress in bulk`(approx:7000 post)`. now after inserting posts in bulk using php script this characters are showing in database so i tried search and replace and some character changed successfully but some don't then i tried `UTF8mb4` got success but still showing some charaters, then i tries `UTF-8` then again some characters change to normal but not all characters

Comment: Do you try in your import script somethink like the php function [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)?

Comment: No I'm using a plugin `CSV Importer`

Comment: Make sure your CSV has the same encoding as the database before importing ;) Here is a list of all UTF characters that usually go wrong and what to search/replace for https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for the same throughout the internet. Finally found a working solution.

I tried method 1 listed on the below website and it works like charm.

Just changed these two lines from wp-config.php:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

with

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Here is the article link: https://samacharpedia.com/fix-strange-character-encoding-issue-wordpress-post-content/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. login into wp admin dashboard
2. Go to add new plugin
3. Search "File Manager"
4. Install and activate it
5. Open file manager and find wp-config.php file
6. Right click on it and open it with code editor
7. Find

   ```
     define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
   ```
8. And just add `-` between utf and 8
9. As follow

   ```
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf-8');
   ```
10. Save and close the wp-config.php file
11. Clear browser cache and refresh the page